AKS Windows pod stuck in terminating state with subpath in volumemounts
AKS Windows based node Pod is stuck in terminating state during deletion/replace of pod whenever I add two volume mounts with subpath. This does not happen if I add single volume mount with subpath.
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
Create a deployment with below volume and volumemounts. Make sure to create the configmap as well.
          volumeMounts:
            - name: configs
              mountPath: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config
              subPath: web.config
            - name: cloudconfig
              mountPath: C:\CloudConfig
              subPath: credentials
      volumes:
        - name: configs
          configMap:
            name: test-report-executor-cm
        - name: cloudconfig
          configMap:
            name: cloud-config

Try running below command:
kubectl replace -n namespace -f filename.yaml --force

Expected behavior
pod should not be stuck in terminating state. The pod is stuck at terminating state for more than 5d now.
Environment (please complete the following information):

CLI Version - v1.27.7
Kubernetes version - 1.27.7

Additional context

Tried below command to check kubelet logs, but it does not show any
logs just a bunch of info about kubelet

more C:\k\kubelet.log


The issue with the Windows-based node pod being stuck in the terminating state during deletion/replace of the pod when adding two volume mounts with subpath is a known issue. This issue occurs because of the way Windows handles file locking. When a file is locked, it cannot be deleted, which causes the pod to get stuck in the terminating state. To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:
Remove the subpath from the volume mount and use the entire volume instead.
Use a different storage driver that supports file locking, such as the SMB driver. delete the old pod and redeploy

To resolve the issue of Windows-based node pods in your AKS cluster being stuck in the terminating state due to problems with volume mounts using sub paths, you can configure the path accordingly and force-delete the stuck pod if necessary.
First ensure your windows node is working fine

then create a ConfigMap that will be used to mount configurations into your pods.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test-report-executor-cm
  namespace: default
data:
  web.config: |
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
  credentials: |
    {
      "username": "testuser",
      "password": "testpassword"
    }




and apply kubectl apply -f configmap.yaml
Create a deployment YAML file, deployment.yaml, using two volume mounts with subpaths:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: windows-pod
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: windows-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: windows-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: windows-app
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": windows
      containers:
      - name: windows-container
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022
        command: ["cmd.exe", "/c", "ping -t localhost"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: configs
          mountPath: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config
        - name: cloudconfig
          mountPath: C:\CloudConfig
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: configs
        configMap:
          name: test-report-executor-cm
      - name: cloudconfig
        configMap:
          name: test-report-executor-cm



apply
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml


Force Delete Stuck Pods using:
kubectl delete pod <pod-name> --grace-period=0 --force --namespace default



If the problem persists due to Windows file locking behavior perform additional troubleshooting steps

Consider using different paths or avoid using subpaths.
If possible, switch to a different storage driver that handles file locks better, like SMB.
do a describe on the stuck pod kubectl describe pod <pod-name> -n <namespace>

References:

Troubleshoot pods and namespaces stuck in the Terminating state
Errors when mounting an Azure file share


This is a confirmed bug that affects only Windows containers. You can workaround avoiding the use of subPath in volume mounts.
See https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/4309
